# Override list_header.tpl file

Tags: php, prestashop

I am new to prestashop, I want to override

```
admin\themes\default\template\helpers\list\list_header.tpl file.
```

I tried by placing above edited file in

```
\override\controllers\admin\templates\helpers\list\list_header.tpl
```

this does not work please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must put your list_header.tpl in:

`/modules/[your_module]/view/templates/admin/_configure/helpers/list/list_header.tlp`

and set

```
$helper->module = $this;
```

in your HelperList instance

Comment: Found the solution by overriding  HelperList class and adding $helper->module = $this;